# DataRowView.SelectedIndex in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I just cant get the SelectedIndex value of first column record in datagrid.
This should works, but I get the System.NullReferenceException.

xaml:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="view5ViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:view5}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource view5ViewSource}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="view5DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Width="300" Height="300">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IDColumn" Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="IsDamagedColumn" Binding="{Binding IsDamaged}" Header="IsDamaged" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Width="75" Height="35" Click="click_event"></Button>
</Grid>
```

cs

```
     private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource view5ViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("view5ViewSource")));
        _context.view5.Load();
        view5ViewSource.Source = _context.view5.Local;
    }

    private void click_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView rowview = view5DataGrid.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
        var id = rowview.Row[0];
        MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? and where are you experiencing errors? I dont see any `SelectedIndex` in your code!

Comment: I mean DataGridRow.SelectedItem, a mistake in Title
and Im trying to achieve the first value of selectedrow in datagrid.

Comment: `System.Data.DataRowView rowview = view5DataGrid.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView` will most probably return NULL. Try `object[] row = view5DataGrid.SelectedItem`

Comment: THANKS it works.

Comment: Mixing binding and some code-behinds is not a good practice though. Use full MVVM sir!